# Can I change my DDR PC 400 to DDR PC 2700?

Tags: memory, ddr

I just want to ask if I can change my DDR PC 400 to DDR PC 2700? I am having a hard time to find a DDR PC 400 here in our place. So Im thinking of replacing it to DDR PC 2700. Is it okay?

Can I use DDR PC 400 and DDR PC 2700 at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that DDR400 is the same as PC3200. So DDR333 is PC2700.

You can mix both but you'll be limited to the lowest speed. So mixing PC3200 with PC2700 end up with DDR333 speeds.

2100, 2700 and 3200 stands for bandwidth speed in MB/s of DDR memory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what bus speed your CPU uses. Generally, on most MBs of that time there were enough options to have multipliers for that sort of thing. As for the second part of the question, yes, DDR400 can work with DDR333 but it will work at 333 speeds. Better state your MB and CPU models and things will be quite clear.